# Cannot GET error, node/express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm making a node/express app with models for users and activities. I've set up an activities.js controller and restful view-pages with placeholder text. When I try to load any of the view pages I'm getting Cannot get error messages (eg "Cannot GET /activities/edit"). The following is an example of how part of the controller is laid out:

```
var Activity = require('../models/Activity');

 function activitiesIndex(req, res){
  Activity.find({}, function(err, activities){
   if(err) return console.error(err);
    else{
 res.render('/activities/index', {
    activities: activities});
      }
  });
}

function activitiesIndex(req, res){
  Activity.findById(req.params.id,
   function(err, activity){
     res.render('/activities/show', {activity: activity});
  });
}
```

Console is showing a server 404 error, which I'm confused by as I've set up views. Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I might be going wrong here?

Thanks very much

Comment: Both of those functions look to have the same name / param list

Comment: That code does not show where you are registering the "/activities/edit" route. Most likely, you just forgot to export those functions to the Express application.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting the same message when trying to get to "/activities/show" though. Will have another look at the name/param lists. Thanks both

Comment: You don't show any routes that handle `/activities/edit`.  Can you show that code?

Comment: Aah, can't believe I've missed that - think that's where I've been going wrong, thanks jfriend00!